# Is it possible to select element by attribute value with webdriverio

Tags: javascript, css, attributes, webdriver-io

I'm writing Jasmine tests for a web app and I have a div element like this:

```
<div data-param1="value1">
    <div>
        .....
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using WebdriverIO and selenium to run my tests with the WDIO Testrunner.
I want to select the div element based on the value of the data-param1 attribute.

What I've tried so far is:

```
browser.getText('div[data-param1*="value1"]');
browser.getText('div[data-param1="value1"]');
browser.getText('[data-param1*="value1"]');
browser.getText('[data-param1="value1"]');
```

But I have no success... In the [Webdriver-IO selector docs](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/selectors.html) I didn't find any example for selector with an attribute.

Can someone please tell me if it is even possible to select an element by the value of its attribute with WebdriverIO?

If someone has managed to do such a selection, I would be grateful if he/she can share an example.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [docs](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/selectors.html#Name_Attribute) state:

> For querying elements with a specific name attribute you can eather use a normal CSS3 selector or the provided name strategy from the JsonWireProtocol by passing something like [name="some-name"] as selector parameter

The reason why your code is not working is that `getText` matches the selector against text content of a node.

Instead, You could try:

```
browser.element('[data-param1="value1"]');
```

or pass the selector directly to the action:

```
browser.click('[data-param1="value1"]');
```

Comment: how can you do this with * search, so you don't need to have the exact phrase of `value1` would it be `browser.element('[data-param1*="val"]');`?